# Exporting WFS to shapefile?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, wfs, geotools

I've installed GeoServer and uploaded a shapefile in it and i want to export this added layer to shapefile using GeoTools library.

I've writtren some code which generates a shapefile(shp,dbf,shx,prj) that contains features without geomertic shape. in the other word it just exports attributes.

pls help me with this problem. where should i revise my code.

here is my code

```
try {
        String getCapabilities = "http://localhost:8060/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities";
        Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
        connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", getCapabilities);
        DataStore data = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connectionParameters); 

        String[] typeNames = data.getTypeNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < typeNames.length; i++) {

            if (!typeNames[i].contains("navahi"))
                continue;
            System.out.println(typeNames[i]);
            SimpleFeatureSource wfsFeatureSource = data.getFeatureSource(typeNames[i]);

            if (wfsFeatureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
                SimpleFeatureType TYPE = wfsFeatureSource.getSchema();




                File newFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + typeNames[i].replace(":", "_") + ".shp");

                System.err.println(newFile.getAbsolutePath());

                ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

                Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
                params.put("url", newFile.toURI().toURL());
                params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

                ShapefileDataStore shpDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);
                shpDataStore.createSchema(TYPE);
                String shpTypeName = shpDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
                SimpleFeatureSource shpFeatureSource = shpDataStore.getFeatureSource(shpTypeName);


                SimpleFeatureStore shpFeatureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) shpFeatureSource;

                SimpleFeatureCollection wfsFeatureCollection = wfsFeatureSource.getFeatures();

                Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");
                shpFeatureStore.setTransaction(transaction);

                try {
                    shpFeatureStore.addFeatures(wfsFeatureCollection);
                    transaction.commit();
                } catch (Exception problem) {
                    problem.printStackTrace();
                    transaction.rollback();

                } finally {
                    transaction.close();
                }

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yeah sure, if i had not why on earth i post this question

Comment: And what is the question? Please edit your post to include a question.

Comment: What happens with your code, do you get any outputs or errors?

Comment: there is no error, exproted layer has no geometry. my code exports just attributes and i need both attributes and geom

Comment: But you said that features do not have geometries. Is your aim a shapefile with all empty geometries?

Comment: No the shapefile which i imported it in geoserver has got both geometry and attributes but when i run my code the exported shapefile has no geometry in it

Comment: All right, much more understandable so. If you want shapefiles out from WFS, why don't you simply make GetFeature with shape-zip outputformat http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely reason to not see a geometry column in a Shapefile is that your column name is not `the_geom`. This is required by the ShapeFile standard - in an ideal world GeoTools would be smart enough to fix this for you behind the scenes, but no one has contributed that code yet!

So you will need to inspect the schema of your features from the WFS and modify the names of any columns that don't fit the ShapeFile standard, i.e. start with an digit, longer than 10 characters etc.

Comment: yes your point was completely right. When i was importing my layer to postgresql i didnt change the geometry column name and the default name was geom so i did it again with the_geom and then i published it in geoserver and when i'd run my code that worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can request a Shapefile via the WFS request to GeoServer.

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

States, WFS returns features and feature information in a number of formats. The syntax for specifying an output format is:

outputFormat=*format*

For ShapeFile

outputFormat=shape-zip

Just add that param to the request URL

Comment: thanks for answering my question although I need my application to be in full connection with geoserver and have list of all layers and their features and attributes and i need to mange all them in memory so Im not able to send a request for all of these stuffs but in some situations i could do make request